# nginx is no longer working on ec2 instance

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, configuration, django, gunicorn

i admittedly ran this:

```
sudo update-rc.d nginx defaults
```

which seemed to wipe out the setup of nginx. Nginx commands like `sudo service nginx start`, etc no longer return anything when executed. However, My nginx files for my django app are still existent in:

```
sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp
sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp
```

I ran a GREP on nginx and got:
[image: img]

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp` contains:

```
server {
        server_name ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com;
        access_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/error/access.log;
        error_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/error/error.log warn;
        connection_pool_size 2048;

        root /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/homelaunch/;

        location /static/ {
            alias /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/homelaunch/static/;
            #alias /static/;
            #root /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/homelaunch/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        }
    }
```

I have gunicorn, django 1.5 running as well

Why can't I use nginx anymore? How can I fix this? All the files still exist in their directories,and nginx is running as a service based on the screenshot above, but no commands are working. Is there someway to restore or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you nginx is NOT running, you see your grep-command; rather run: `netstat -pltn | grep nginx`

please run the following commands (root or sudo):

- `which nginx` -> get the path to binary
- `nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` -> test nginx config
- `nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` -> start nginx with given config
- `netstat -pltn | grep nginx` -> see on which ports nginx is listening

Comment: Wow, this worked! So should i be using nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf instead?

Comment: Instead of sudo service nginx start

Comment: no, you shouldnt.